# while true loop doesn't work inside another in python

Tags: python, while-loop

I have a `while true` loop (code below) within another loop. I want to check if you clicked on a button and if so, change the cursor into an image that I have imported before. I tried to do that by hiding the cursor and let an image follow it. But when I run this, it hides the cursor draws the image where the it was, but doesn't move with the cursor.

```
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == MOUSEBUTTONUP:
            mousex, mousey = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
            if mousex > 100 and mousex < 200 and mousey > 50 and mousey < 100:  # a button on my screen 
                pygame.mouse.set_visible(False)
                while True:
                    mousex, mousey = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
                    DISPLAYSURF.blit(cursorImg, (mousex,mousey))
                    pygame.display.update()
```

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong please?

Comment: your second loop will never end, you need to `break` it if you want the first loop to be iterated again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code to this:

```
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == MOUSEBUTTONUP:
            mousex, mousey = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
            if mousex > 100 and mousex < 200 and mousey > 50 and mousey < 100:  # a button on my screen 
                pygame.mouse.set_visible(False)
                mousex, mousey = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
                DISPLAYSURF.blit(cursorImg, (mousex,mousey))
    pygame.display.update()
```